# Can Java GC local variables that are in scope but no longer used?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In the following code:

```
void method() {
   HeavyObject heavy = new HeavyObject();
   doStuffWith(heavy);
   doOtherStuff();
}
```

...can `heavy` be garbage collected before or during `doOtherStuff()`?  JLS references preferred, though actual experiments would be cool too.

My goal is to determine whether or not `heavy = null` is strictly useless, or might conceivably have *some* benefit.